# How to pass a List from the controller to jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp

I am implementing a bulletin board with spring framework.

To show the list of articles on jsp, I got some info from DB and saved it to `List<BulletinBoardList>`.

What I want to do is to take this List to jsp and save it. I tried with the code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    /*
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
    
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
    */
    List<BulletinBoardList> result = sqlSession.selectList("board.getList");
    
    model.addAttribute("list", result);
    

    
    
    return "home";
}
```

Next, this code is for retrieving the List from controller:

```
<%@ page import com.heesu.third.BulletinBoardList, java.util.List %>
<% BulletinBoardList list = ${list} %>
```

But it never works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done such thing using jstl in jsp. Take a look in my code. Here my list is "inf" and my objects have different fields, but I think you will manage to adapt it:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Real time info</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <caption><h3>Result (People):</h3></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr class="tr tr-success">
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>PIN</td>
                </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${inf}" var="temp">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${temp.id}</td>
                        <td>${temp.name}</td>
                        <td>${temp.pin}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-info" href="/update-person?id=${temp.id}">Update</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" href="/delete-person?id=${temp.id}">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is that specific part of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleRequest(@RequestParam String search,
            ModelMap model){
        List<UserInfo> inf = searchServ.listPeople(search);
        model.put("inf", inf);
        return "info";
    }
```

Your thing is very similar. I hope that will help you. Just to add - I am using bootstrap to style my graphical user interface.

Comment: thanks! it was very helpful!. I voted for you, but since my level is too low it's not publicly displayed.

Comment: happy that it helped you!